# cakephp find multiple sets of OR in conditions

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have seen another question that technically answers what I'm answering, but my query is not working.  I think the query is self explanatory but it's not returning any rows.

[CakePHP find conditions with multiple 'OR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290696/cakephp-find-conditions-with-multiple-or)

```
$sector_info['Notam'] = $this->Notam->find('all', array(
                    'group' => 'Notam.id',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'AND' => array(
                            'OR' => array(
                                'Notam.notam_expire_dtg < '.date("YmdHis"),
                                'Notam.notam_expire_dtg' => '',
                                ),
                            'OR' => array(
                                'Notam.account_id' => $sector_info['Airport']['identifier'],
                                'Notam.cns_location_id' => $sector_info['Airport']['identifier'],
                                'Notam.account_id' => $sector_info['Airport']['icao'],
                                'Notam.cns_location_id' => $sector_info['Airport']['icao'],
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    )
                );
```

I want to pull notams that are (not expired, or have no expiration) AND ( OR the other 4 conditions.

Thanks in aadvance,
 Ryan

EDIT: This is the query that outputs, doesn't mention Notam.notam_expire_dtg at all:

```
SELECT `Notam`.`id`, `Notam`.`key`, `Notam`.`source_id`, `Notam`.`account_id`, `Notam`.`notam_id`, `Notam`.`notam_nrc`, `Notam`.`xoveraccountid`, `Notam`.`xovernotamid`, `Notam`.`notam_part`, `Notam`.`cns_location_id`, `Notam`.`icao_id`, `Notam`.`icao_name`, `Notam`.`total_parts`, `Notam`.`notam_effective_dtg`, `Notam`.`notam_expire_dtg`, `Notam`.`notam_lastmod_dtg`, `Notam`.`notam_text`, `Notam`.`notam_report`, `Notam`.`notam_qcode`, `Notam`.`pull`, `Notam`.`dflag`, `Notam`.`sql_update` FROM `aaid_cake`.`notams` AS `Notam` WHERE ((`Notam`.`account_id` IN ('PABE', 'BET')) OR (`Notam`.`cns_location_id` IN ('PABE', 'BET'))) GROUP BY `Notam`.`id`
```

Comment: date("YmdHis") or date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ?   'Notam.notam_expire_dtg <'  => 'date("YmdHis"),

Comment: the date component is correct, We're not using the mysql date format we're using the format received in the database every 5 minutes 'YmdHis'  The query worked before I added the two 'OR's inside the 'AND' I had the date element outside of the 'OR' but this does not include rows that have have no value ''

Comment: 'Notam.id' is unique id ?

Comment: yes, coppied from another query that joined a bunch of tables and had dupes.  I'll remove that too, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
$sector_info['Notam'] = $this->Notam->find('all', array(
                'group' => 'Notam.id',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'OR' => array(
                            'Notam.notam_expire_dtg < '.date("YmdHis"),
                            'Notam.notam_expire_dtg' => '',
                     ),
                    'AND'=>array(
                     'OR' => array(
                            'Notam.account_id' => $sector_info['Airport']['identifier'],
                            'Notam.cns_location_id' => $sector_info['Airport']['identifier'],
                            'Notam.account_id' => $sector_info['Airport']['icao'],
                            'Notam.cns_location_id' => $sector_info['Airport']['icao'],
                            )
                        ),                            
                    ),
                )
            );
```

Comment: The little green checkmark in the post above your post indicates the question has been accurately answered already.

Comment: but you said that you were going to try..so I have given you the complete answer. A thanks would be also great even if you don't need the answer

Comment: Thanks for helpping, I really do wish we had a larger cakephp community here.  I didn't mean to sound discouragong

Answer (score 2):

php basics: You **can't** have duplicate array keys, your 2nd declaration of `['OR']`is overriding the first. This should make your mistake obvious.

Try this:

```
'conditions' => [
    'AND' => [
        ['OR' => [/*...*/]],
        ['OR' => [/*.../*]]
    ]
 ]
```

Comment: Brilliant! I will try that after lunch. Thanks!